# Cannot install yesod with "duplicate instance declaration"

Tags: haskell, yesod

When I try to install yesod using the command "cabal install yesod", I got the following errors:

```
cabal install rsa
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring RSA-1.0.6.1...
Preprocessing library RSA-1.0.6.1...
Preprocessing executables for RSA-1.0.6.1...
Building RSA-1.0.6.1...
[1 of 1] Compiling Codec.Crypto.RSA ( Codec/Crypto/RSA.hs, dist/build/Codec/Crypto/RSA.o )

Codec/Crypto/RSA.hs:577:10:
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance Random Word8 -- Defined at Codec/Crypto/RSA.hs:577:10-21
      instance Random Word8 -- Defined in System.Random
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
```

It seems RSA lib conflicts with another library.

Any idea?

My environment:
Mac OS X 10.7
GHC 7.0.3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a little more background, this is called the [Orphan Instance](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Orphan_instance) problem if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `random` package started exporting new instances in version 1.0.1.0. One solution would be to conditionally compile the RSA library's instance only when the `random` package is that version or later; some variation like this should work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
#if MIN_VERSION_random(1,0,1)
#else
instance Random Word8 where
    ...
#endif
```

Bonus points if you send a patch to the maintainer of the RSA library.

Alternately, you could ask cabal to use an older version of `random`.